# i tried to install julia "https://datatofish.com/add-julia-to-jupyter/" and coding but i have this error

Tags: anaconda, julia, jupyter

i tried to install julia 
"https://datatofish.com/add-julia-to-jupyter/"
and coding but i have this error

```
(v1.1) pkg> add IJulia
   Cloning default registries into `C:\Users\hp\.julia`
   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:OS, failed to send request: A connection with the server could not be established
)

(v1.1) pkg>
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Can you improve your question with punctuation and appropriate markdown formatting, so it can become more readable? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you checked if [proposed solutions in this discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/error-giterror-code-error-class-os-failed-to-send-request-a-connection-with-the-server-could-not-be-established/10192) can help you?